# How to protect data with conditions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code :

```
function Lock(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var protection = sh.protect().setDescription('DATA');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F2:F").createTextFinder("^(?!OK!).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll().map(r => r.offset(0, 0, 1, 2)));
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()){
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

This code working great. It will protect Row if column F:F is correct value is `OK!`. And now i want it to protect if the value is `OK!` or `Failed!`

`.createTextFinder("^(?!OK!).*$")`

Where should I modify it? i tried `||` but can not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F2:F").createTextFinder("^(?!OK!).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll().map(r => r.offset(0, 0, 1, 2)));
```

#### To:

```
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F2:F").createTextFinder("^(?!(OK!|Failed!)).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll().map(r => r.offset(0, 0, 1, 2)));
```

and

```
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F2:F").createTextFinder("^(?!OK!)(?!Failed!).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll().map(r => r.offset(0, 0, 1, 2)));
```

- In this modification, `^(?!OK!).*$` is modified to `^(?!(OK!|Failed!)).*$` and `^(?!OK!)(?!Failed!).*$`.

Comment: Thanks again haha, i just thought it would work with ```||```

Comment: @Leti Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.